# How to print a .txt file content in a html site with javascript every 1 s?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a file in my directory which is constantly changing itself. So every 1 second my file is saved and has a diffenent content. How can I display the file content in a HTML site using javascript in a way that the file content is updated in real time or every 1 s?

I tried this code but the site just opens the pop-up window where the file content is and every time I want to see changes, I have to press F5, I don't want that.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<title>test</title>
<body>
<a href="output.txt">test</a><br>

    <script>
        var w = window.open('output.txt'); //Required full file path.
        w.print();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go along the lines of

```
</head>
<title>test</title>
<body>
<a href="output.txt">test</a><br>
    <div id="text" ></div>
    <script>
        setInterval(()=>{
               let t=new XMLHttpRequest()
               t.open('GET',location.origin+'output.txt')
               t.onreadystatechange=(ev)=>{
                   if(ev.readyState==4){    
                       document.getELementById('text').textContent=t.responseText;
                      }
                };
                t.send()
         },1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

this way you wont get a new popup every second
another way would be :

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<title>test</title>
<body>
<br>
    <iframe id="text" src="output.txt" />
    <script>

        setInterval(()=>{ 
            document.getElementById("text").contentWindow.location.reload();
         },1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you might need some small changes at `location.origin+'output.txt'` to correctly point to your text file

Comment: Can I avoid that link to my file, like when I open the site, the content is automatically displayed?

Comment: Thanks for the code, Jonathan, but the site is just showing the link to the file and when I open the file again I have to use F5 to refresh the file content :/

Comment: in the second example it should open a new tab that gets refreshed every second oO (dont click on the link I jsut left that in there on accident ^^ you also need to allow popups )

Comment: Like I said, when I open my .html document with the browser, I can see just the link, but no the file content :/

Comment: have you allowed popups for the site ?

Comment: ok i created and embedded example which doenst need popups (could use some resizing though oO)

Comment: Yes, Popups are allowed on the website :)
The problem is, when I open the website, I don't see the file content. It is just a white site. :D

Comment: oh I just realized I was missing a bracket btw if you try code it helps if have press f12 first that opens the developer console and lets you see if bugs occur

Comment: Hmmmm
The frame shows the file content but the problem is that the code does not refrash the file content. So every time I want to see the "new" content (new lines in the file), I have to refresh the site :/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<title>test</title>
<body>
<a href="output.txt">test</a><br>

    <script>
        var w = window.open('output.txt'); //Required full file path.
        w.print();
        setInterval(function() {
            window.location.reload(true);
        }, 1000)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```